# Changing port in launchSettings.json gives "This site can’t be reached"

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core

I created an empty asp.net core app using VS2017. Only thing I changed is the  `"sslPort":` property in the launchSettings.json file.
When I click run IIS Express chrome opens with url `https://localhost:9995/` and gives the `This site can't be reached The connection was reset.` error

My launchSettings.json is the following

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false, 
    "anonymousAuthentication": true, 
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:39566",
      "sslPort": 9995
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "JccWeb2": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As stated in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/using-iis-express/handling-url-binding-failures-in-iis-express#using-a-custom-ssl-port), you use an incompatible port for ssl with IIS Express.
Instead of `"sslPort": 9995`, replace with a port number between 44300 and 44399.

> If you want to test SSL access to your site, you can do this with IIS Express by using an SSL port between 44300 and 44399 and using the IIS Express self-signed certificate. Trying to use SSL with a port outside this range results in a URL binding failure when your website is launched under IIS Express.

Comment: You are right. Had to change the port to one in the range above

Comment: thank you, this is very important, and I finally get this here

Comment: You can not give 44399 it will throw error "Unable to connect to web server 'IIS Express'. You have option from 44300 to 44398.